# Extracting message body from email chains - python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to extract the message body from emails. My current code works well with regular emails that only have a single message body (one conversation) but not with email chains containing multiple emails. For example, this email below was forwarded by multiple people:

---------------------- Forwarded by Phillip K Allen/HOU/ECT on 09/26/2000 02:00 PM --------------------------- Reschedule Chairperson: Richard Burchfield Sent by: Cindy Cicchetti Start: 10/03/2000 02:30 PM End: 10/03/2000 03:30 PM Description: Gas Physical/Financail Positions - Room 2537 This meeting repeats starting on (if the date occurs on a weekend the meeting ). Meeting Dates: Fletcher J Sturm/HOU/ECT Scott Neal/HOU/ECT Hunter S Shively/HOU/ECT Phillip K Allen/HOU/ECT Allan Severude/HOU/ECT Scott Mills/HOU/ECT Russ Severson/HOU/ECT Detailed description: ---------------------- Forwarded by Phillip K Allen/HOU/ECT on 09/26/2000 02:00 PM --------------------------- Confirmation Chairperson: Richard Burchfield Sent by: Cindy Cicchetti Start: 10/03/2000 02:30 PM End: 10/03/2000 03:30 PM Description: Gas Physical/Financail Positions - Room 2537 This meeting repeats starting on (if the date occurs on a weekend the meeting ). Meeting Dates: Fletcher J Sturm/HOU/ECT Scott Neal/HOU/ECT Hunter S Shively/HOU/ECT Phillip K Allen/HOU/ECT Allan Severude/HOU/ECT Scott Mills/HOU/ECT Russ Severson/HOU/ECT Detailed description: Status update: Fletcher J Sturm -> No Response Scott Neal -> No Response Hunter S Shively -> No Response Phillip K Allen -> No Response Allan Severude -> Accepted Scott Mills -> Accepted Russ Severson -> No Response ----------------------

And I want to extract the main content only but it still has the weird thing like this.

```
---------------------- Forwarded by Phillip K Allen/HOU/ECT on 09/26/2000 02:00 PM ----------------------
```

I couldn't come up with lines of code that exclude this weird thing and only pick up the main body so I just removed them (e.g. punctuation like - and /, the dates, and the specific words like "forwarded") when I cleaned my data after extraction. But I'd like to know if there is a way to exclude this thing and only pick up the main body part while I do the extraction. Here is my current code for the extraction part:

```
# Extract message body
def extract_body(messages):
    column = []
    for message in messages:
        e = email.message_from_string(message)
        payload = e.get_payload()
        payload = ' '.join(payload.split())
        column.append(payload)
    return column

emails_df['Body'] = extract_body(emails_df['message'])
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are missing details in your question. What kind of object is "email" in your code? which packages are you using to extract the data?